# Filter image smoothly in html5 canvas.

Tags: html, canvas

I need to have an image filtered and then with the mouse move erase the filter and leave the image on its original format.
For that I am thinking about having two canvas the one upon the other with
a relative transparent filter on the top.

```
 <div style="position: relative;">
<canvas id="picture-layer" width="100" height="100" 
style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas
<canvas id="filter-layer" width="100" height="100" 
style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Then how can I erase the filter-layer filter on the mouse move and reveal the image from below ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page loads, you could call a function that fills the filter canvas with a semi-transparent color. For example...

```
function fillFilterCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("filterCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)";
    context.fill();    
}
```

When the mouse moves over the filter canvas, you could call a function that clears part of the filter canvas near the mouse position. For example...

```
function clearFilterCanvas(x, y) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("filterCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var width = 20;
    var height = 20;
    context.clearRect(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height);
}
```

From the mouse move event handler, you would call the clearFilterCanvas() function with the mouse's position in the filter canvas. For example...

```
function filterCanvas_mousemove(e) {
    clearFilterCanvas(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to smoothen the edges of the clearRect function ?

Comment: You could use a clipping path to exclude parts of the clearRect. For example, the following clears a circle centered on the (x,y) position.

    function clearFilterCanvas(x, y) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("filterCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var radius = 10;
        context.save();
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.clip();
        context.clearRect(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        context.restore();
    }